# Aligning input boxes on a form side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align to input text boxes of a form side by side but i not able to do so. Please help.

Fiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rHh3w/1/)

HTML:

```
<p>Your Name
<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
    <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true"
</span> 
</p>
<p>Your Email
<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
    <input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7- validates-as-email" aria-required="true">
</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.wpcf7 input[type="text"], .wpcf7 input[type="email"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML code is wrong. One of your span and inputs aren't closed.

Comment: Where is your class name wpcf7-form-control-wrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rHh3w/12/show

Just need to set your `p` element to "`display:inline;`" by default they are block elements and will not align next to each other.

also deleted two  `br` tags

```
p {display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<br />` from your HTML markup.

Write:

```
p{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap input[type="text"],.wpcf7-form-control-wrap input[type="email"] {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Note:

`inline-block` leaves white space between elements. Write elements on same line to avoid it.

Like write

```
</p><p>
```

(on same line)

rather than

```
</p>
<p>
```

(on different lines)

[**Fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rHh3w/11/)

Comment: In your fiddle the `input` elements aren't side by side like the OP asked.

Comment: Your missing a closing `</span>` in the second `p`.

Comment: I removed the downvote but I would also mention about the _whitespace_ problem when using `display:inline-block`.

Comment: @Vucko I have already written `</p><p>` on same line to avoid white-space problem. you didnt notice that.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/LHE4W/)

What I have done is added the following:

```
    p {
      float: left;
    }
```

That's all you need to do, it also means that if your container width goes below the fixed width of the two input boxes together, they will float down over two lines rather than breaking and spilling out of their container.

While you're at it, it might be worth changing the text labels to [actual labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), this will allow the user to click on the label and still highlight the form, which is growing increasingly important due to the rise in mobile use.

Also, you missed a closing `>` of your first input box.

Comment: this is not the answer. You might have written this as comment.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ I wish it were that simple, but I would require 50 reputation to comment on anything that I haven't posted.

Answer (score 1):

How about display them like a table.

```
.myForm {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.myForm div {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:table-cell;
}
.myForm div:last-of-type{
    text-align:right;
}
```

`.myForm div:last-of-type` Align text to the right side.

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/463QF/

Answer (score 0):

Try below `CSS` for p tag

```
    p
    {
        width:auto;
        float:left;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
```

If you need some space between text box then u can set margin-right to the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your CSS code : `p{width:40%;border:1px solid #000;float:left}` 

**Fiddle :**http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/PSQ7u/

Answer (score 0):

HTML example:

```
<div class="myForm">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Your name</label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">your email</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myForm div {
    width: 47%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
} 

.myForm div label
{
    display:block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Jna/1/)